# Scrapy pipeline TypeError: spider_opened() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to learn Scrapy. I've written a custom pipeline to save spider output to xls. However, there's an error in pipelines.py that's related to spider_opened() method.

Gist with log: https://gist.github.com/codenotfound/3ebbd292eba8e25af0b1 (error on lines 10-25)

Pipelines.py on github: http://is.gd/pipelines_py (lines 32-57)

Everything seems to work fine - items are scraped and saved to files, except 2 things:

1. This strange TypeError
2. Header line is not written to .xls file, even though the code for it is in spider_opened method of XlsExportPipeline

I'm new to Scrapy so I'm looking for your advice on this problem.

Comment: The TypeError is because the spider_opened() method does not get an item argument, it only gets the spider (details here: http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html?highlight=spider_opened#scrapy.signals.spider_opened)

Comment: Well, that was easy :). I had to access item fields by importing from bot.items. Thanks for your help! On a different note, do you know if it's possible to have multiple FEED_URIs? I tried to assign an array to FEED_URI, but that didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure about multiple FEED_URIs, but since you writing your own pipeline, you could use a spider attribute and get it with ``getattr(spider, 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HERE')``.

Comment: Nice tip, but I want to make use of default feed exports, such as csv, json, xml. So that by default scrapy saves multiple files under different formats. Custom pipeline is not in the equation, since it's not connected to FEED_URI or FEED_FORMAT.